# No provider for NgControl after changing value accessor initialization

Tags: angular, angular-forms, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

I have created one custom input control with value accessor.

This was my code before

```
@Component({
    selector: "app--input",
    templateUrl: "./app-input.component.html",
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppInputComponent), multi: true }
    ]

})
```

I wanted to access form control so i changed logic to this.

```
@Component({
    selector: "app--input",
    templateUrl: "./app-input.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app-input.component.scss"]
})
export class AppInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {
    controlDirective: any;
    constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
        //this.checkValidation();
        controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.controlDirective = this.controlDir.control;
    }
}
```

My issue is that i am using this input to just display values at some places & that doesn't contain any form. So i use one input param to set value in this input.

I was working with first method.

But after i changed logic to above, without ngModel or formControlName it's giving me below error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for NgControl
```

How can i avoid this error with this implementation?

Comment: have you import `FormsModule` in AppModul

Comment: Yes. Its' not related to this. When i use this control without ngModel or formControl then it's giving me this error.

Comment: You can use `constructor (@Optional() @Self() public controlDir: NgControl)`, if the NgControl is optional, but remember check `if (controlDir)` each time you want to use the variable, and really I don't know how you can show values if you has no [(ngModel)] or [formControl] or formControlName